# Searching for cell value in a different excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel workbook (lets call serial_numbers) that contains a list of S/N on `A1` to `A10` (can be more or less).

Now I have to search for `A1`'s value on workbook "database". That value is usually found in `A1` cell of workbook "database".

In case that I find `A1`'s valueI need to copy and paste `B2`'s value of workbook "database", which cointains the current stock of that value.

Through Developer mode on Excel I got the following result:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Check stock for S/N in database
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="database.xlsx", _
        UpdateLinks:=0
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="XXXXXX", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("B1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("serial_numbers.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

That piece above seems to be not working properly and since Im new to this I cant get why. Can any of you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for non-vba solution then you may go for `vlookup function`.

Try this code :

```
Sub testMacro()

    Dim wkbDB As Workbook
    Dim rngFind As Range, rngSearch As Range, cell As Range
    Dim shtDB As Worksheet


    Set wkbDB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\database.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=0)
    Set shtDB = wkbDB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set rngSearch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

    For Each cell In rngSearch
        Set rngFind = shtDB.Range("A1:A10").Find(What:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            'serial_numbers.xlsx
           cell.Offset(0, 1) = rngFind.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @GabrielPicareli Any reason for not accepting the answer. To know how accept answer see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/about).